# ionic input elements have zero width, height

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm new to ionic and inherited a code base for an unfinished app that I'm trying to complete. The current forms use standard HTML tags for forms instead of the ionic tags (e.g. input instead of ion-input). Below is some standard HTML I built for a new form, but the inputs are rendered in the browser with 0 width and 0 height so they're effectively not editable. Am I making a common mistake? Is there something in the scss that needs to be set? TIA.

```
<ion-view view-title="Add Card">
  <ion-content>
    <form>
      <div class="list">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>Card Number</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="cardNumber" placeholder="#### #### #### ####"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>Exp. Date</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="expDate" placeholder="MM/YY"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>CVV</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="cvv" placeholder="MM/YY"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
    <button ion-button type="submit" block>Save Card</button>
  </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I run your code without any scss and `<ion-view>` element and everything works fine. Can you upload an image of what it looks like on your side?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZN4aEBj

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `ion-view`

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-reactive-form)

HTML"

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="callSubmit()">
        <div class="list">
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label fixed>Card Number</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" formControlName="cardNumber" placeholder="#### #### #### ####"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label fixed>Exp. Date</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" formControlName="expDate" placeholder="MM/YY"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label fixed>CVV</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" formControlName="cvv" placeholder="MM/YY"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </div>
        <button ion-button type="submit" block>Save Card</button>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      cardNumber: null,
      expDate: null,
      cvv: null
    })
  }

  callSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. I took the ion-view out but it didn't help. I haven't actually put in the controller code yet. Could that be inhibiting the from from rendering correctly?